# Play migration to 2..6 and Scala 2.12 : Compilation issue while using WithFilter

Tags: scala, playframework

Recently I have upgraded the play to 2.6 and scala to 2.12. Below code was working fine with previous version, but now its trowing compilation error in upgraded version.

```
object Global extends WithFilters {

override def doFilter(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = {
Filters(super.doFilter(next), CustomOverridingFilter)
}

override def onError(request: RequestHeader, throwable: Throwable) = {
//Some code here
super.onError(request, throwable)
}

override def onStart(app: Application) = {
//Some code here
super.onStart(app)
}

override def onStop(app: Application) = {
//Some Code Here
}
}

object CustomOverridingFilterextends Filter {

override def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])
(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
//Some Code Here
}
}
```

Getting Compilation error as below:
not found: type WithFilters
value doFilter is not a member of AnyRef
value onStart is not a member of AnyRef

Play : 2.6
Scala: 2.12

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

`WithFilters` exists in Play 2.5, but it was already deprecated.

I guess it has been removed in 2.6. You need to rewrite your app to remove any global state, which means classes instead of objects.

See the [2.6 migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26)

Actually, removing global state has been prepared earlier in 2.4 already, see the [2.4 migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/GlobalSettings) for details:

> Also, mind that if your Global class is mixing the WithFilters trait, you should now create a Filter class that inherits from HttpFilters, and place it in the empty package. Read here for more details.

```
class Filter extends HttpFilters {
  ...
}
```

Note, before attempting to upgrade to a newer version, it is always a good idea to not use any deprecated APIs in your code (which you should hardly tolerate in general).

Comment: Hi, Can you please share any dummy code snippet to convert the above code for scala 2.12 support...i am clueless like, from where to inherit...i will be greatfull to ur help

Comment: Note, it is not specific to the Scala version, this is a change of the Play API.

Comment: I added a code snippet, which is basically the thing what the migration guide told you. Note, there is also a link you should follow with more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot cbley. I am able to write the CustomOverridingFilterextends . But now I feel I need to remove the GlobalSettings. So I need to re-write object Global extends WithFilters . I went through the miration guide, its really difficult to understand how to remove the global settings. I did not get any sample code in github..any help here

Comment: As per the doc:  "GlobalSettings.onStart: Anything that needs to happen on start up should now be happening in the constructor of a dependency injected class. A class will perform its initialization when the dependency injection framework loads it. "   Does it mean I need to remove the object Global completely and write a new class like:  public class StartUp{ //Here will implement the onStart code}. Then the question is who will call this. I am really struggling here, any light on this..

Comment: Yes, you should remove `Global` and `GlobalSettings`. I don't know what you need to do in `onStart`, but you need to use dependency injection: `class AClass @Inject() (app: Application) { ... /* initialization here */ }`